# Yii framework time() not the same as the behavior time()

Tags: php, time, frameworks, yii

I try to update de last_login_time in my user table, but the time() is always 5h higher than the updatedTime behavior with the function

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return array(
        'timestamps' => array(
            'class' => 'zii.behaviors.CTimestampBehavior',
            'createAttribute' => 'create_time',
            'updateAttribute' => 'update_time',
            'setUpdateOnCreate' => true,
        )
    );
}
```

My function to update the last_login_time is very simple:

```
private function userLogedin()
{
    $user = User::model()->findByPk($this->auth->user_id);
    $user->last_login_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time());
    return $user->save();
}
```

How can i have the same time than the behaviors one? Is there a way more kindly to create this kind of update?

Thank you very much! I'm a newb with Yii, it's my first app, so be kind please ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`CTimestampBehavior`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.12/framework/zii/behaviors/CTimestampBehavior.php) sets the time based on the *database server's* local time, as reported by [`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now). Your code sets the time based on the *web server's* local time, as reported by [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php).

The timezone difference between the two servers should account for the 5 hour discrepancy.

If you want to achieve the same effect as `CTimestampBehavior` with similar syntax as your own code, you will have to use [`CDbExpression`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbExpression):

```
$user = User::model()->findByPk($this->auth->user_id);
$user->last_login_time = new CDbExpression('NOW()');
return $user->save();
```

There's also an example of the same [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/10/how-to-automate-timestamps-in-activerecord-models/).